# chartjs and making an onClick action for a specific element?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, element

Suppose we have a scatterplot with 2 points, and a handler for when a specific point is clicked. As an example, suppose when the left point is clicked i want `console.log("You clicked me!")` to happen. But when the right point is clicked, nothing happens (aside from default chartjs behavior)

Is it possible to do this? I think it should be easy, **if** i can somehow access the point I want as an element (left point in the above the example).

- I don't know how to do this, or if it is possible though?
- I imagine it should be, since I imagine each point is a distinct element to make hovering and tooltips to work?

To put it differently, suppose I have a code snippet like the one below (the snippet makes a chart with 2 points), and I want some code like this, **except with b as the left (first) point of the chart instead of my button from the html**

Edit: Note: I know I can make the chart respond to a click (for a point). I am asking about how to make clicking on different points do different things. Maybe `.getElementsAtEventForMode(e, mode, options, useFinalPosition)` can someone be restricted to clicks in certain areas?

```
<button id="mybutton">Click me</button>
<script>
let b = document.querySelector("#mybutton");
b.onclick = function() { console.log("You clicking me!"); };
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <Title> Chart </Title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p> Ex chart go</p>
        <div>
            <canvas id = "myChart"></canvas>
        </div>







        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
        <script>
            const ctx = document.getElementById(`myChart`);

            const scatterData = [{
                x:2,
                y:10
            },{
                x:4,
                y:10
            }]
            const toPlot = {
                // labels:xval,
                datasets: [{
                    // label: "Ex chart",
                    data: scatterData,
                    backgroundColor: "rgb(255,0,0)"
                }]
            };
            let myChart= new Chart(ctx, {
                type: `scatter`,
                data: toPlot,
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        x: {
                            min:1,
                            max:5,
                        }
                    }
                },
        })
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please dont remove your questions and post them again, in case you dont get usefull answers try to edit your question to be more clear instead of reposting them

Answer (score 0):

One way we can do this, if we know some property of the point we want (such as x value in the example below), is to just use a conditional statement, like If, in the event handler function (i.e. in the function that says what happens when the chart is clicked on).

I feel like this is a better way to do this, but the approach does work.

Note: to see behavior click on left point, then click on right, and see difference

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <Title> Chart </Title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p> Ex chart go</p>
        <div>
            <canvas id = "myChart"></canvas>
        </div>







        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
        <script>
            const ctx = document.getElementById(`myChart`);

            const scatterData = [{
                x:2,
                y:10
            },{
                x:4,
                y:10
            }]
            const toPlot = {
                // labels:xval,
                datasets: [{
                    // label: "Ex chart",
                    data: scatterData,
                    backgroundColor: "rgb(255,0,0)"
                }]
            };
            let myChart= new Chart(ctx, {
                type: `scatter`,
                data: toPlot,
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        x: {
                            min:1,
                            max:5,
                        }
                    }
                },
        });
        
        function clickHandler(evt) {
                const points = myChart.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, 'nearest', { intersect: true }, true);

                if (points.length) {
                    const firstPoint = points[0];
                    var label = myChart.data.labels[firstPoint.index];
        var value = myChart.data.datasets[firstPoint.datasetIndex].data[firstPoint.index];
            if (1.5<value.x && value.x<2.2) {
        console.log("You clicked me!");
    }
                }
            }

    ctx.onclick = clickHandler;
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```